# How to save information in the browser memory and display when pressed without refreshing the page using the react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

I load information about the user's language from the local storage when opening the page and also have buttons in the interface for changing the language. But how can I do it without refreshing the page on JS React, so that when I press the button, the language changes without reloading the page?

```
  componentWillMount() {
    let language = localStorage.getItem('language');
    this.setLanguage(language);
  }
```

SetLanguage method:

```
  setLanguage(language) {
    i18next.init({
      lng: language,
      resources: require(`../localization/${language}.json`)
    });
    i18next.changeLanguage(language, (err, t) => {
      if (err) return console.log('something went wrong loading', err);
      t('applog'); // -> same as i18next.t
    });
  }
```

Example code for using localization:

```
<span className="dataTitle">{i18next.t('welcome')}</span>
```

For locatization i use i18next library

Comment: As a beginning, you should use this bit of code inside `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount` to make sure the `component` and `window` are mounted and loaded, to prevent such errors like `can't read property getItem of undefined`.

Comment: you'll need to save the changes in state, for example`title: hello` and on press button  set title to a different language `title: Hola`.

Comment: The code you are representing is not what causes the refresh, it's mostly the `button` a user clicks to change the language, which -the refresh` in this case, is necessary!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `state` to store `language`, and `onClick` of button you need to change state using `this.setState` which will re-render your component with new `language`,

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      language: '',
    }
}
```

On button press,

```
changeLanguage = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('language', 'Hindi')
    let language = localStorage.getItem('language')
    console.log(language)
    this.setLanguage(language)
}
```

```
setLanguage = language => {
    this.setState({language})
    //Your othe code here
}
```

Simplified [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-nxgv3?fontsize=14).

Comment: How can this work when translation loading is asynchronous? If you are going to use the set state way, you have to setState inside the callback. https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#changelanguage

Comment: @UniqIdentifierAssignedAtBirth i don't know, but it works

Comment: Maybe because you are testing it on a local server the file loads in time for the render

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the change in language is external to state. When the language is changed a re-render is not triggered. You can trigger a re-render by using the built-in [`forceUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) method. Like so,

```
setLanguage(language) {
    i18next.init({
      lng: language,
      resources: require(`../localization/${language}.json`)
    });
    i18next.changeLanguage(language, (err, t) => {
      if (err) return console.log('something went wrong loading', err);
      t('applog'); // -> same as i18next.t

      this.forceUpdate();
    });
  }
```